# C++ vectors Doesnt recognize [i] INSPITE of the code being EXACTLY IDENTICAL to video tutorial

Tags: c++11, vector

be considerate, this is my first post; first foray into C++!

This is the exact frame where I used the code from this video:
https://youtu.be/Cq1h1KPoGBU?t=340

this is what I wrote down:

```
vector<int>         myVector;
             myVector.push_back(3);
    std::cout << " Vector:  ";
                
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++);
     {std::cout << myVector[i] << "    ";  }
                     //(this "[i]" claims to be undefined by C++)//
     std::cout << "enter variables" << endl;
```

C++ says that "i" is undefined at the italicized line (where I have an arrow pointed at the concerned line)

Yes, I included 
Please help!

Comment: You added a `;` at the end of the line with your for-loop. It's not there in the video. This treats the for-loop as a no-op and the next line is a completely new scope without `i`.

Comment: Thanks guys and gals

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of the line

```cpp
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++); // <-- here
```

Because of that, the `for` loops body is considered to be empty. (And the curly braces (`{`) just open a code block.)

The code should look like this:

```cpp
vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(3);
std::cout << " Vector:  ";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) // notice no ; here
{
  std::cout << myVector[i] << "    ";  
}
std::cout << "enter variables" << endl;
```